# Is there a way to add mp3 files into a C++ file?

Tags: c++, mp3

I am currently working on a video game as a school project. I have code that opens an MP3 file in a media player, but is there a way to edit my code so that it plays the music in the c++ file? I am using the Quincy 2005 compiler, and have not added any new libraries.

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
//replace music with your filename
system("start music.mp3");
}
```

Comment: Things such as MP3 files are referred to as "resources" or "assets" and are external to the programming itself.  Most commonly, they are retrieved from a separate file at a location that is known to the software.  Occasionally, they are bundled in with the application (as a resource) but once again are not part of the programming [that you'd be writing with C++ ...]

Comment: It's possible to put music into an EXE file, yes (and I'm not sure why nobody does it). But how will you play it? This runs Windows Media Player, right? I don't think Windows Media Player knows how to play MP3 files out of EXE files. You could get your program to play it itself, but it's a bunch of work that maybe you don't want to do.

Comment: I am using a DELL Chromebook that the school has supplied us. When the program is ran, it opens an app called Groove Music. I believe this is different than Windows Media Player. How would I turn an MP3 file into an EXE file, then how would I include that into a c++ program? Thank you all for your help so far.

Comment: @RyanHricenak you don't "TURN an MP3 file INTO an EXE file", you STORE the MP3 INSIDE an EXE file. How you "include that into a c++ program" is highly platform dependent. For instance, on Windows, you would use an `.rc` file to compile the MP3 into a `.res` file, and then *link* that into your EXE file as an embedded resource. At runtime, your code can then access the MP3 data using the Win32 `FindResource()`/`LoadResource()`/`LockResource()` functions, for instance to give the MP3 to the Win32 `PlaySound()` function, or to a library you compile into your program code to play MP3s.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help